# Projeto - Banda Desenhada (Prancha)

Tags: java

Tenho um projeto de Introdução à Programação que consiste em fazer uma banda desenhada. A primeira classe é a Vinheta. É preciso criar dois construtores para a Vinheta, que, num deles recebe como argumentos uma `ColorImage`, um `int` que representa a espessura, um `int` tipo e uma `Color`, e no outro recebe tudo menos a `Color`. Isto porque, é suposto criarmos molduras na Vinheta, daí a espessura, o tipo (que pode ser, linha, tracejado ou desenhado) e a cor (que é a cor da moldura).

Depois é necessário criar vários métodos para saber a altura e largura da vinheta, alterar a cor, espessura, tipo, passar a imagem para preto e branco e voltar às cores originais. Tudo isto está feito. A minha questão prende-se com a segunda classe: Prancha. A Prancha é uma matriz de vinhetas, com várias tiras (é necessário criar o método para dizer quantas tiras queremos) e cada tira terá de ter várias vinhetas (é necessário criar o método para dizer quantas vinhetas em cada tira individual queremos, isto é, uma tira poderá levar uma vinheta e outra poderá levar 3).

Terei de criar também um método que fará com que possa haver um espaçamento entre as vinhetas e a tira seguinte. A matriz está criada e também o método para criar o método para escolher quantas tiras queremos, mas agora é preciso desenhar a prancha, definir o método para saber a altura, largura, o número de vinhetas de uma tira, o espaço entre vinhetas e tiras e colocar uma vinheta numa dada posição (substituindo a que estava nessa posição anteriormente).
Gostaria que me ajudassem no que puderem, sendo que o mais importante neste momento é desenhar a prancha, a altura e a largura.

[image: VER ESTA IMAGEM PARA PERCEBER COMO DEVERÁ FICAR]

Código Vinheta (a moldura tracejada está mal, se alguém souber):

```
import aguiaj.iscte.Color;
import aguiaj.iscte.ColorImage;


class Vinheta {

//CONSTRUTOR    
    ColorImage img;
    private ColorImage vinheta;
    int moldura;
    int tipo;
    Color color;
    private boolean preto_branco=false;

//FORNECENDO COR
    Vinheta(ColorImage img, int moldura, Color color, int tipo) {
        this.img=img;
        this.moldura=moldura;
        this.tipo=tipo;
        this.color=color;
        if(tipo==0)
        semMoldura(img,moldura);
        else if(tipo==1)
        linha(img, moldura, color);
        else if(tipo==2)
        tracejado(img,moldura,color);
        else if(tipo==3)
        desenhado(img,moldura,color);
    }



//ASSUMINDO QUE A COR É PRETO
        Vinheta(ColorImage img, int moldura, int tipo) {
        this.img=img;
        this.moldura=moldura;
        this.tipo=tipo;
        if(tipo==0)
        semMoldura(img,moldura);
        else if(tipo==1)
        linha(img, moldura, Color.BLACK);
        else if(tipo==2)
        tracejado(img,moldura,Color.BLACK);
        else if(tipo==3)
        desenhado(img,moldura,Color.BLACK);
    }



//VINHETA SEM MOLDURA
    private void semMoldura(ColorImage img, int moldura){   
        ColorImage img2 = new ColorImage(this.img.getWidth() + moldura*2, this.img.getHeight() + moldura*2);
        for(int x=0; x<this.img.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<this.img.getHeight(); y++) {
                img2.setColor(x+moldura,y+moldura,this.img.getColor(x,y));
            }
        }
            this.vinheta=img;
    }

//MOLDURA LINHA
    private void linha(ColorImage img, int moldura, Color color){
        ColorImage img2 = new ColorImage(this.img.getWidth() + moldura*2, this.img.getHeight() + moldura*2);
            for(int x=0; x<this.img.getWidth(); x++) {
                for(int y=0; y<this.img.getHeight(); y++) {
                        img2.setColor(x+moldura,y+moldura,this.img.getColor(x,y));
                }
            }
                for(int i=0; i<img2.getWidth(); i++) {
                    for(int j=0; j<img2.getHeight(); j++) {
                        if(i <= moldura-1 || j <= moldura-1 || i >=img2.getWidth()-moldura || j >= img2.getHeight()-moldura) {
                            img2.setColor(i, j, color);
                        }
                    }
                }
            this.vinheta=img2;          
    }




//MOLDURA TRACEJADA
    private void tracejado(ColorImage img, int moldura, Color color) {
            ColorImage img2 = new ColorImage(this.img.getWidth() + moldura*2, this.img.getHeight() + moldura*2);
                for(int x=0; x<this.img.getWidth(); x++) {
                    for(int y=0; y<this.img.getHeight(); y++) {
                        img2.setColor(x+moldura,y+moldura,this.img.getColor(x,y));
                    }
                }

                for(int i=0; i<img2.getWidth(); i++) {
                    for(int j=0; j<img2.getHeight(); j++) {
                        //if(i%2==0 && j<=moldura || j%2==0 && i<=moldura){
                            if(i <= moldura-1 || j <= moldura-1 || i >=img2.getWidth()-moldura || j >= img2.getHeight()-moldura) {
                            img2.setColor(i,j,color);
                        }
                    }
                }
        this.vinheta=img2;
    }


//MOLDURA DESENHADA
    private void desenhado (ColorImage img, int moldura, Color color){
        ColorImage img2 = new ColorImage(this.img.getWidth() + moldura*2, this.img.getHeight() + moldura*2);
            for(int x=0; x<this.img.getWidth(); x++) {
                for(int y=0; y<this.img.getHeight(); y++) {
                    img2.setColor(x+moldura,y+moldura,this.img.getColor(x,y));
                }
            }       
            for (int i=0;i!=img2.getWidth();i++){
                for (int j=0;j!=img2.getHeight();j++){
                    if(i<moldura || i>=img2.getWidth()-moldura || j<moldura || j>=img2.getHeight()-moldura){
                        int n=(int)(Math.random()*11);
                        if(n%2!=0)
                            img2.setColor(i,j,color);
                    else{
                        Color c=new Color (255,255,255);
                        img2.setColor(i,j,c);
                    }
                    }
            if(i>=moldura && i<img2.getWidth()-moldura && j>=moldura && j<img2.getHeight()-moldura){
                Color f = img.getColor((i-moldura),(j-moldura));
                        img2.setColor(i,j,f);           
            }
                }
            }
            this.vinheta=img2;
    }

//DEFINIR A COR DA MOLDURA          
    void changeColor (Color color){
        this.color=color;
        if(tipo==0)
        semMoldura(img,moldura);
        else if(tipo==1)
        linha(img, moldura, color);
        else if(tipo==2)
        tracejado(img,moldura,color);
        else if(tipo==3)
        desenhado(img,moldura,color);
    }

//DEFINIR O TIPO DA MOLDURA
    void changeTipo(int tipo){
        this.tipo=tipo;
        if(tipo==0)
        semMoldura(img,moldura);
        else if(tipo==1)
        linha(img, moldura, color);
        else if(tipo==2)
        tracejado(img,moldura,color);
        else if(tipo==3)
        desenhado(img,moldura,color);
    }

//DEFINIR A ESPESSURA DA MOLDURA    
    void changeEspessura(int moldura){      
        this.moldura=moldura;
        if(tipo==0)
        semMoldura(img,moldura);
        else if(tipo==1)
        linha(img, moldura, color);
        else if(tipo==2)
        tracejado(img,moldura,color);
        else if(tipo==3)
        desenhado(img,moldura,color);
    }           


//ALTURA VINNHETA           
    public int altura() {
        return vinheta.getHeight();
    }   

//LARGURA VINHETA
    int largura() {
        return vinheta.getWidth();
    }

//PASSAR DE CORES PARA P&B
    void colorToGray() {
        for(int x=moldura; x<vinheta.getWidth()-moldura; x++)
            for(int y=moldura; y<vinheta.getHeight()-moldura; y++)
                vinheta.setColor(x,y,vinheta.getColor(x,y).toGraytone());
    }

//VOLTAR ÀS CORES ORIGINAIS
    void coresOriginais(){
        for(int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++)
            for(int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++)
                vinheta.setColor(x+moldura, y+moldura, img.getColor(x,y));
    }

//DEVOLVER A IMAGEM CORRESPONDENTE À VINHETA
    ColorImage getVinheta(){
        if(preto_branco==false)
            return this.vinheta;
        else{
            colorToGray();
        return this.vinheta;
        }
    }

}
```

Código feito da Prancha até agora:

```
import aguiaj.iscte.ColorImage;
import aguiaj.iscte.Color;

class Prancha {

//CONSTRUTOR
    Vinheta[][]m;
    ColorImage prancha;
    private int espacamento;
    private int nTiras;
    private int numeroDeVinhetas;



    Prancha (int nTiras){
        m = new Vinheta[nTiras][1];
            for(int x=0; x>nTiras; x++){
                    m[x][0]=new Vinheta(new ColorImage (50,50), 1, 1);
            }
    int espacamento=0;

}
```

Esses imports têm a ver com o AguiaJ, um programa criado por um professor da minha faculdade, que nós usamos no Eclipse

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida?